# 'Dynamically-related files could not be resolved' error in Dreamweaver

Tags: wordpress, localhost, dreamweaver, mamp

I'm using Dreamweaver (CS5) to manipulate a Wordpress template, however when I try and use 'live view' on a themes index.php file I receive the error:

"Dynamically-related files could not be resolved because of an internal server error".

My local host however appears to be working fine and correctly displays the index.php file located on my top tier directory.

Many users have resolved this error by turning perma-links to default, however mine are already set this way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**This isn't a solution, but merely a reference for someone else who is having a similar issue.**

I had the same issue using the /%postname%/ permalink structure, but when I returned to the "Default" structure, it discovered the files fine.

If you're just testing a design before implementation, I suggest leaving it to "Default" on your testing server. Or, if you haven't already, create a testing server.

Comment: Yup, I just did that like 2 minutes ago and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem i fixed by changing Permalinks to custom structure and below there is Option ->category base give a name and try it. Dreamweaver knows all dynamically related files after all.

Selecting default permalinks structure also works on DW CS5. Hope this helps.